# Identifying and consolidating duplicated observations

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, missing-data

I'm working on the data for a clinical trial. In this data, there are multiple observations that refer to the same patient and they have varying degrees of missing data. I have four variables which I'm using as identifiers and I've decided that, if a patient has identical values for three out of the four variables, that he/she should be considered a duplicate.

The degree of missing data in all of these variables is extremely low, so there's not an issue of a patient having three NA's and being considered a duplicate of another one with three NA's.

I've been able to remove the duplicates by creating the `comb`inations of variables and using the `dplyr::distinct()` . Unfortunately, this leads to one of the observations being kept, which might have missing data that an observation for the same patient had, but was excluded. I'll demonstrate with some fake data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

tibble(Name = c("Pedro", "Pedro","Pedro","Cristina","Walter","Sara","Mateus"),
       Birth = dmy(c("29/07/1994","29/07/1994","29/07/1994","01/04/1960", "22/12/1956", "20/02/1997","25/07/1994")),
       CNS = c("700",NA,"700","701","702","703","704"),
       Document = c("104","104",NA,"105","106","107","108"),
       SystolicBP1 = c(NA,NA,120,160,152,114,NA),
       DiastolicBP1 = c(NA,NA,80,100,100,92,NA),
       SystolicBP2 = c(NA,NA,NA,148,NA,NA,100),
       DiastolicBP2= c(NA,NA,NA,90,NA,NA,82),
       HBA1c = c(7,7,7,8.2,8,9,6.5)) -> dt

kable(dt)
```

| Name | Birth | CNS | Document | SystolicBP1 | DiastolicBP1 | SystolicBP2 | DiastolicBP2 | HBA1c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pedro | 1994-07-29 | 700 | 104 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 7.0 |
| Pedro | 1994-07-29 | NA | 104 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 7.0 |
| Pedro | 1994-07-29 | 700 | NA | 120 | 80 | NA | NA | 7.0 |
| Cristina | 1960-04-01 | 701 | 105 | 160 | 100 | 148 | 90 | 8.2 |
| Walter | 1956-12-22 | 702 | 106 | 152 | 100 | NA | NA | 8.0 |
| Sara | 1997-02-20 | 703 | 107 | 114 | 92 | NA | NA | 9.0 |
| Mateus | 1994-07-25 | 704 | 108 | NA | NA | 100 | 82 | 6.5 |

I can then run the following to get rid of the duplicates, but I end up losing some data:

```
identifiers <- c("Name","Birth","CNS","Document")

combn(identifiers, 3) -> comb

kable(comb)
```

> |  |  |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Name | Name | Name | Birth |
> | Birth | Birth | CNS | CNS |
> | CNS | Document | Document | Document |

```
## this takes the result of distinct() for each 
## combination of the 4 identifiers, taken 3 at a time
dt %>% 
        distinct (!!! syms(comb[,1]), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
        distinct (!!! syms(comb[,2]), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
        distinct (!!! syms(comb[,3]), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
        distinct (!!! syms(comb[,4]), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
        kable()
```

> | Name | Birth | CNS | Document | SystolicBP1 | DiastolicBP1 | SystolicBP2 | DiastolicBP2 | HBA1c |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Pedro | 1994-07-29 | 700 | 104 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 7.0 |
> | Cristina | 1960-04-01 | 701 | 105 | 160 | 100 | 148 | 90 | 8.2 |
> | Walter | 1956-12-22 | 702 | 106 | 152 | 100 | NA | NA | 8.0 |
> | Sara | 1997-02-20 | 703 | 107 | 114 | 92 | NA | NA | 9.0 |
> | Mateus | 1994-07-25 | 704 | 108 | NA | NA | 100 | 82 | 6.5 |

My goal is, when faced with missing data, to try to get the missing data from the duplicate observations. If I could do this, in the example above the first observation would've gotten the values for "SystolicBP1" and "DiastolicBP1" from the third observation in the original tibble.

Answer (score 0):

We could create strings out of the first four ident-columns and run `hclust` based on string distances from `adist` to get `id`s. Next, using `by`, we split the data along these `id`s and reduce to one row, leaving either first value or `NA`.

```
> cl_fun <- \(data, h., ident=c("Name", "Birth", "CNS", 'Document')) {
+   strings <- Reduce(paste0, data[ident])  ## create ident strings
+   ld  <- adist(tolower(strings))  ## distance matrix
+   hc <- hclust(as.dist(ld))  ## cluster analysis
+   id <- cutree(hc, h=h.)  ## cut tree to groups
+   within(data, id <- id)  ## add id to data
+ }
> na_fun <- \(.) {
+   o <- vapply(., \(x) {
+     o <- if (all(is.na(x))) {
+       NA_character_
+     } else {
+       na.omit(as.character(x))[[1]]
+     }
+   }, FUN.VALUE=character(1))
+   o <- type.convert(as.data.frame(t(o)), as.is=TRUE)
+   within(o, {Birth <- as.Date(Birth)})
+ }
> by(cl_fun(df, h.=8.0), ~id, na_fun) |> do.call(what='rbind')
      Name      Birth CNS Document SystolicBP1 DiastolicBP1 SystolicBP2 DiastolicBP2 HBA1c id
1    Pedro 1994-07-29 700      104         120           80         100           NA   7.0  1
2 Cristina 1960-04-01 701      105         160          100         148           90   8.2  2
3   Walter 1956-12-22 702      106         152          100          NA           NA   8.0  3
4     Sara 1997-02-20 703      107         114           92          NA           NA   9.0  4
5   Mateus 1994-07-25 704      108          NA           NA         100           82   6.5  5
6      Ana       <NA>  NA       NA         130           94         100           89    NA  6
```

Ordep is considered as a duplicate of Pedro, and Laura is considered as a duplicate of Ana, which is fine according to your statements. As tuning parameter in `cl_fun()` I use `h` from `cutree()`, which specifies the height if you plot `hc`, you could also try `k` instead, which would specify the number of clusters with the disadvantage, though, that `k` is an integer and less flexible. You could also specify more arguments of `adist()` such as `costs` to fine-tune. In this `h=8.0` produced the wanted result.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c("Pedro", "Pedro", "Pedro", "Ordep", "Cristina", 
"Walter", "Sara", "Mateus", "Ana", "Ana", "Laura"), Birth = structure(c(8975, 
8975, 8975, 8975, -3562, -4758, 9912, 8971, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    CNS = c("700", "<NA>", "700", "700", "701", "702", "703", 
    "704", NA, NA, NA), Document = c("104", "104", "<NA>", "104", 
    "105", "106", "107", "108", NA, NA, NA), SystolicBP1 = c(NA, 
    NA, 120L, NA, 160L, 152L, 114L, NA, NA, 130L, 120L), DiastolicBP1 = c(NA, 
    NA, 80L, NA, 100L, 100L, 92L, NA, 94L, NA, 96L), SystolicBP2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 100L, 148L, NA, NA, 100L, 100L, 110L, 110L), DiastolicBP2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 90L, NA, NA, 82L, 89L, NA, 91L), HBA1c = c(7, 
    7, 7, NA, 8.2, 8, 9, 6.5, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looks like:

```
> df
       Name      Birth  CNS Document SystolicBP1 DiastolicBP1 SystolicBP2 DiastolicBP2 HBA1c
1     Pedro 1994-07-29  700      104          NA           NA          NA           NA   7.0
2     Pedro 1994-07-29 <NA>      104          NA           NA          NA           NA   7.0
3     Pedro 1994-07-29  700     <NA>         120           80          NA           NA   7.0
4     Ordep 1994-07-29  700      104          NA           NA         100           NA    NA
5  Cristina 1960-04-01  701      105         160          100         148           90   8.2
6    Walter 1956-12-22  702      106         152          100          NA           NA   8.0
7      Sara 1997-02-20  703      107         114           92          NA           NA   9.0
8    Mateus 1994-07-25  704      108          NA           NA         100           82   6.5
9       Ana       <NA> <NA>     <NA>          NA           94         100           89    NA
10      Ana       <NA> <NA>     <NA>         130           NA         110           NA    NA
11    Laura       <NA> <NA>     <NA>         120           96         110           91    NA
```

Comment: In your example, if I had another row in which the Name was Ordep, Birth was 1994-07-29, CNS was 700 and Document was 104, it wouldn't combine them, right?

My understanding of your code is that it checks if Name and Birth are equal. What I'm trying to do is check if any 3 out of the 4 identifiers are equal, if they are, consider the observations duplicated and maintain the first value that isn't NA for each variable. In the example, this makes no difference, but in the original data it does.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @PedroHenriqueFaria I see. Please see revised answer which now uses a cluster analysis approach.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is take the first non-`NA` value from each group, then we can do

```r
library(dplyr)
dt |>
  summarize(
    .by = c(Name, Birth),
    across(everything(), ~ na.omit(.x)[1])
  )
# # A tibble: 5 × 9
#   Name     Birth      CNS   Document SystolicBP1 DiastolicBP1 SystolicBP2 DiastolicBP2 HBA1c
#   <chr>    <date>     <chr> <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Pedro    1994-07-29 700   104              120           80          NA           NA   7  
# 2 Cristina 1960-04-01 701   105              160          100         148           90   8.2
# 3 Walter   1956-12-22 702   106              152          100          NA           NA   8  
# 4 Sara     1997-02-20 703   107              114           92          NA           NA   9  
# 5 Mateus   1994-07-25 704   108               NA           NA         100           82   6.5
```

This (silently) discards multiple rows for a `Name, Birth` pair that may have differing values (not present in the sample data). We can show this by changing one value and seeing that it is dropped:

```r
dt2 <- mutate(dt, Document = replace(Document, 1, "999"))
head(dt2, 3)
# # A tibble: 3 × 9
#   Name  Birth      CNS   Document SystolicBP1 DiastolicBP1 SystolicBP2 DiastolicBP2 HBA1c
#   <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Pedro 1994-07-29 700   999               NA           NA          NA           NA     7
# 2 Pedro 1994-07-29 NA    104               NA           NA          NA           NA     7
# 3 Pedro 1994-07-29 700   NA               120           80          NA           NA     7

dt2 |>
  summarize(
    .by = c(Name, Birth),
    across(everything(), ~ na.omit(.x)[1])
  )
# # A tibble: 5 × 9
#   Name     Birth      CNS   Document SystolicBP1 DiastolicBP1 SystolicBP2 DiastolicBP2 HBA1c
#   <chr>    <date>     <chr> <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Pedro    1994-07-29 700   999              120           80          NA           NA   7  
# 2 Cristina 1960-04-01 701   105              160          100         148           90   8.2
# 3 Walter   1956-12-22 702   106              152          100          NA           NA   8  
# 4 Sara     1997-02-20 703   107              114           92          NA           NA   9  
# 5 Mateus   1994-07-25 704   108               NA           NA         100           82   6.5
```

If this is the case, we can make the process a little smarter by imputing values (I'll use random sampling of non-`NA` values) and then deduplicating.

```r
dt2 |>
  mutate(
    .by = c(Name, Birth),
    across(everything(), ~ if_else(is.na(.x), na.omit(.x)[1], .x))
  ) |>
  distinct()
# # A tibble: 6 × 9
#   Name     Birth      CNS   Document SystolicBP1 DiastolicBP1 SystolicBP2 DiastolicBP2 HBA1c
#   <chr>    <date>     <chr> <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Pedro    1994-07-29 700   999              120           80          NA           NA   7  
# 2 Pedro    1994-07-29 700   104              120           80          NA           NA   7  
# 3 Cristina 1960-04-01 701   105              160          100         148           90   8.2
# 4 Walter   1956-12-22 702   106              152          100          NA           NA   8  
# 5 Sara     1997-02-20 703   107              114           92          NA           NA   9  
# 6 Mateus   1994-07-25 704   108               NA           NA         100           82   6.5
```

One side-effect of doing `na.omit(.x)[1]` is that if all values (in that group for that column) are `NA`, then while `na.omit(.x)` will return `c()`, the `[1]` will force it to return `NA`.

FYI, the use of `.by=` requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer; if you have an older version, change from `mutate(.by=c(..), stuff)` to `group_by(..) |> mutate(stuff) |> ungroup()`.

Comment: As with the answer above, my understanding is that your code checks only if name and birth are equal, right?

What I'm trying to do is check if 3 out of the 4 identifiers are equal, if they are, consider the observations duplicated and keep the first non-NA observation for each variable.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Okay, I understand. That starts to explode a bit with regards to the possible combinations; it's tenable, certainly, but I don't have time to work on at atm. If I can, I will loop back to this if I have time (not today/tomorrow). Good luck! @PedroHenriqueFaria

Comment: I think I managed to use what you wrote to do what I needed. I added a row with a new observation that wouldn't work unless the combinations were doing the trick.

```
dt %>% add_row(Name = "Ordep", Birth = dmy("29/07/1994"), CNS = "700", Document = "104") -> dt

identifiers <- c("Name","Birth","CNS","Document")
combn(identifiers,3) -> comb

for (i in seq(1,4)){
        dt %>%
                summarize(
                        .by = comb[,i],
                        across(everything(), ~ na.omit(.x)[1])
                ) -> dt
}
```

And the output is the same as yours.